# Getting compilation error , expected end of statement in vb script..

Tags: vbscript

I have written a simple hello world program

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/vbscript">
document.write("Hello World")
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

saved as hello.vbs. I tried to run in cmd and by double clicking it. But I am getting the above compilation error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A command line script can't contain neither HTML markup (`<whatever>`) nor reference components provided by the browser (`document`).

A hello word VBScript should look like

```
WScript.Echo "Hello world"
```

or

```
MsgBox "Hello world"
```

depending on whether you want to use a console (`cscript hello.vbs`) or wscript/double click on `hello.vbs`.

(cf. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript#Hello.2C_World))